# What should I learn to be able to study Mobius transforms?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, mobius-transformation

I'm currently a student who is very interested in the Mobius transform. However, I tried reading some papers on the topics, and with my current knowledge of maths, I am not able to completely comprehend much of the language of the subject (ie. automorphism). I'm trying to write a research paper on mathematics and Mobius transforms are one of the topics I would like to cover, so any help would be much appreciated.

Here are some of the sources I've looked at:
http://www.math.bas.bg/~rkovach/lectures/Moebius.pdf

http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/papers/moebius.pdf

Comment: Automorphism usually refers to invertible map from a space onto itself. I think most of the topics in first link are very basic introduction to Mobius transforms. It's probably good idea to cover some elementary complex analysis and their relation to Riemann sphere and some related geometry, but none of these require any deep knowledge to follow the articles you linked

Comment: Have you taken an undergraduate course on complex analysis? If so, perhaps a good starting point would be to read the Mobius transformation section of a graduate complex analysis book. I know they are covered in an early chapter of Conway's book, but I don't remember how in depth he goes. An by "research paper," I assume you mean expository paper? Another good option: find a professor who regularly teaches complex analysis, and ask him or her to recommend a friendly introductory paper or book chapter for you to read.

Comment: Are you aware of Douglas Arnold's and Jonathan Rogness' video [_Möbius Transformations Revealed_](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/moebius)?